# How can I fix this multicolumn to not destroy my table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]{Erstmalig im Inland in Verkehr gebrachte Düngemittel}
    \caption{Düngemittel Reinnährstoffabsatz von 1995/96 bis 2013/14 (Menge in t)}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}|}
            \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth=0,25mm}
            \hline \rowcolor{brown!80}
            Jahr    & Stickstoff (N)    & Phosphor (\ce{P2O5})  & Kalium (\ce{K2O}) \\
            \hline \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2013/14 & 111.615   & 32.731    & 32.559 \\
            
            2011/12 & 97.721    & 26.198    & 32.478 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2009/10 & 90.639    & 22.121    & 23.356 \\
            
            2007/08 & 134.382   & 44.704    & 49.787 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2005/06 & 103.692   & 34.979    & 40.738 \\
            
            2003/04 & 100.789   & 39.357    & 49.532 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2001/02 & 127.585   & 47.138    & 50.099 \\
            
            1999/00 & 121.644   & 48.548    & 55.241 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            1997/98 & 127.537   & 57.264    & 61.537 \\
            
            1995/96 & 125.309   & 52.272    & 59.755  \\
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{l}{Quelle: https://www.ama.at/getattachment/f3f479f8-6bc9-42e3-be83-d8fd4112a937/281\_Dungemittel\_Reinnahrstoffabsatz-ab-1995.pdf (besucht am 20-01-2024)}
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I am pretty new to latex and can't get this multicolumn to work. I basically need this link at the bottom to span over several rows, but i couldn't make it work with the command multirow.

Comment: Make the multicolumn a p column instead of l.  You have 16cm + 6\tabcolsep to play with.  BTW, you can move `\arrayrulewidth=0,25mm` outside the tabular but inside the table.  You can move global changes to the preamble.  Also, table (normally) does not have a required argument, so the "Ernstmalig ..." is simply treated as a line of text.

Comment: Also, you should use `\url` (url package) to handle the odd characters in the url.

Comment: Welcome. // Please add the missing lines at the beginning, so your code will compile once we copied it. Thank you.

Comment: Don't scale tables using `\resizebox` (or `\scalebox`). This is always poor typesetting. And don't limit the float options to `h`. Despite LaTeX does always use `ht`, if `h` does not work, I would always recommend to also allow `p`. And if a table really must not float, you should not use a float. And please, next time don't show a code snippet, but a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` and with all packages loaded that are needed for the LaTeX run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the package `xurl` you don't have to worry about url hypenation (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407368/101651)).

I also used `threparttable` for the table notes and an ordinary `tblr` (just to give you another alternative w.r.t. NonnoDino's one from which I started).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\NewColumnType{V}[1]{X[m,c,si={table-format=#1}]}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, exponent-product=\cdot}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Düngemittel Reinnährstoffabsatz von 1995/96 bis 2013/14 (Menge in t)}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={|X[m,c]|V{3.3}V{2.3}V{2.3}|},
row{even} = {brown!20}, row{1} = {brown!80}
}
\toprule
Jahr    & {{{Stickstoff (N)}}}    & {{{Phosphor (\ce{P2O5})}}}  & {{{Kalium (\ce{K2O})}}} \\
\midrule
2013/14 & 111.615   & 32.731    & 32.559 \\
2011/12 & 97.721    & 26.198    & 32.478 \\
2009/10 & 90.639    & 22.121    & 23.356 \\
2007/08 & 134.382   & 44.704    & 49.787 \\
2005/06 & 103.692   & 34.979    & 40.738 \\
2003/04 & 100.789   & 39.357    & 49.532 \\
2001/02 & 127.585   & 47.138    & 50.099 \\
1999/00 & 121.644   & 48.548    & 55.241 \\
1997/98 & 127.537   & 57.264    & 61.537 \\
1995/96 & 125.309   & 52.272    & 59.755  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\begin{tablenotes}
Quelle = \url{https://www.ama.at/getattachment/f3f479f8-6bc9-42e3-be83-d8fd4112a937/281_Dungemittel_Reinnahrstoffabsatz-ab-1995.pdf} (besucht am 20-01-2024)
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you are writing an official document and nobody obliged you to use that style, it should be better to use a professional table, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, exponent-product=\cdot}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{S[table-format =#1]}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\centering
\caption{Düngemittel Reinnährstoffabsatz von 1995/96 bis 2013/14 (Menge in t)}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{cV{3.3}V{2.3}V{2.3}}
\toprule
Jahr    & {Stickstoff (N)}    & {Phosphor (\ce{P2O5})}  & {Kalium (\ce{K2O})} \\
\midrule
2013/14 & 111.615   & 32.731    & 32.559 \\
2011/12 & 97.721    & 26.198    & 32.478 \\
2009/10 & 90.639    & 22.121    & 23.356 \\
2007/08 & 134.382   & 44.704    & 49.787 \\
2005/06 & 103.692   & 34.979    & 40.738 \\
2003/04 & 100.789   & 39.357    & 49.532 \\
2001/02 & 127.585   & 47.138    & 50.099 \\
1999/00 & 121.644   & 48.548    & 55.241 \\
1997/98 & 127.537   & 57.264    & 61.537 \\
1995/96 & 125.309   & 52.272    & 59.755  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
Quelle = \url{https://www.ama.at/getattachment/f3f479f8-6bc9-42e3-be83-d8fd4112a937/281_Dungemittel_Reinnahrstoffabsatz-ab-1995.pdf} (besucht am 20-01-2024)
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your nice inputs, I will try them all out. The three part table as you use, looks so much simpier! Just one question, what are the curly braces in the toprule for?

Comment: @LukasE. If you put the text into curly braces, `siunitx` does not consider it. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `url` package, which provides the `\url` command specifically designed for typesetting URLs. I've also utilized `\parbox` to create a paragraph, allowing me to write the URL on multiple lines. Here is your modified code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{url} % <--- I have added this package here
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Düngemittel Reinnährstoffabsatz von 1995/96 bis 2013/14 (Menge in t)}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}|}
            \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth=0,25mm}
            \hline \rowcolor{brown!80}
            Jahr    & Stickstoff (N)    & Phosphor (\ce{P2O5})  & Kalium (\ce{K2O}) \\
            \hline \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2013/14 & 111.615   & 32.731    & 32.559 \\
            
            2011/12 & 97.721    & 26.198    & 32.478 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2009/10 & 90.639    & 22.121    & 23.356 \\
            
            2007/08 & 134.382   & 44.704    & 49.787 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2005/06 & 103.692   & 34.979    & 40.738 \\
            
            2003/04 & 100.789   & 39.357    & 49.532 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            2001/02 & 127.585   & 47.138    & 50.099 \\
            
            1999/00 & 121.644   & 48.548    & 55.241 \\
            \rowcolor{brown!20}
            1997/98 & 127.537   & 57.264    & 61.537 \\
            
            1995/96 & 125.309   & 52.272    & 59.755  \\
            \hline
            % I have modified the line below ⬇
            \multicolumn{4}{l}{\parbox{\linewidth}{Quelle: \url{https://www.ama.at/getattachment/f3f479f8-6bc9-42e3-be83-d8fd4112a937/281_Dungemittel_Reinnahrstoffabsatz-ab-1995.pdf} (besucht am 20-01-2024)}}
    \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: original]

However, I do think that this is poorly typeset. I would suggest using the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, which offers many options such as the ability to set specific colors for ranges of cells, columns, or rows (even the option to specify for even and odd). `tabularray` also supports notes below tables. Here is the code for creating the table with the `tabularray` package:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\NewColumnType{V}[1]{X[m,c,si={table-format=#1}]}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center, exponent-product=\cdot}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{longtblr}[caption={Düngemittel Reinnährstoffabsatz von 1995/96 bis 2013/14 (Menge in t)},
remark{Quelle} = {\quad\parbox{0.85\linewidth}{\url{https://www.ama.at/getattachment/f3f479f8-6bc9-42e3-be83-d8fd4112a937/281_Dungemittel_Reinnahrstoffabsatz-ab-1995.pdf}\\(besucht am 20-01-2024)}}]{colspec={|X[m,c]|V{3.3}V{2.3}V{2.3}|},
row{even} = {brown!20}, row{1} = {brown!80}
}
\toprule
Jahr    & {{{Stickstoff (N)}}}    & {{{Phosphor (\ce{P2O5})}}}  & {{{Kalium (\ce{K2O})}}} \\
\midrule
2013/14 & 111.615   & 32.731    & 32.559 \\
2011/12 & 97.721    & 26.198    & 32.478 \\
2009/10 & 90.639    & 22.121    & 23.356 \\
2007/08 & 134.382   & 44.704    & 49.787 \\
2005/06 & 103.692   & 34.979    & 40.738 \\
2003/04 & 100.789   & 39.357    & 49.532 \\
2001/02 & 127.585   & 47.138    & 50.099 \\
1999/00 & 121.644   & 48.548    & 55.241 \\
1997/98 & 127.537   & 57.264    & 61.537 \\
1995/96 & 125.309   & 52.272    & 59.755  \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Both the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) and [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) packages can be used in a simple tabular environment. The first provides the option to perfectly typeset numbers (in this example, you can see that all the numbers have been aligned vertically by the dot), and the second one provides better spacing between rows and horizontal rules specifically designed for tables, such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.

Comment: You've also appropriately removed the `\resizebox`.  booktabs would argue that you should still remove the vertical rules and the shading.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that the source is inside the tabular.

With the code below I avoid `\resizebox` (***never*** use it for tables). Only a few computations are necessary and, a posteriori, a small trick in order for the Phosphor column header to fit.

Using `siunitx` is recommended.

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{caption}

\newlength{\colwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]

%% {Erstmalig im Inland in Verkehr gebrachte Düngemittel}

\caption{Düngemittel Reinnährstoffabsatz von 1995/96 bis 2013/14 (Menge in~t)}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.25mm}
\setlength{\colwidth}{\dimeval{(\textwidth-3\arrayrulewidth-8\tabcolsep)/4}}

\begin{tabular}{
  |w{l}{\colwidth-0pt}|
  S[table-format=3.3,table-column-width=\colwidth]
  S[table-format=2.3,table-column-width=\colwidth]
  S[table-format=2.3,table-column-width=\colwidth]
  |
}
\hline \rowcolor{brown!80}
Jahr & {Stickstoff (\ce{N})} & {\makebox[0pt]{Phosphor (\ce{P2O5})}} & {Kalium (\ce{K2O})} \\
\hline \rowcolor{brown!20}
2013/14 & 111.615   & 32.731    & 32.559 \\

2011/12 & 97.721    & 26.198    & 32.478 \\
\rowcolor{brown!20}
2009/10 & 90.639    & 22.121    & 23.356 \\

2007/08 & 134.382   & 44.704    & 49.787 \\
\rowcolor{brown!20}
2005/06 & 103.692   & 34.979    & 40.738 \\

2003/04 & 100.789   & 39.357    & 49.532 \\
\rowcolor{brown!20}
2001/02 & 127.585   & 47.138    & 50.099 \\

1999/00 & 121.644   & 48.548    & 55.241 \\
\rowcolor{brown!20}
1997/98 & 127.537   & 57.264    & 61.537 \\

1995/96 & 125.309   & 52.272    & 59.755  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip

\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
  Quelle: \url{https://www.ama.at/getattachment/f3f479f8-6bc9-42e3-be83-d8fd4112a937/281\_Dungemittel\_Reinnahrstoffabsatz-ab-1995.pdf} (besucht am 20-01-2024)%
}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the standard classes are set up for captions below the table; there *must* be vertical space between them.

What you put in braces after `\begin{table}[h]` is a bit mysterious. In any case, just `[h]` is an error.