paragraph look sparse in footnote?
I have a paragraph footnote like this:
dữ liệu\footnote{là phép biến đổi tuyến tính một vector ngẫu nhiên có ma trận hiệp phương sai cho trước thành một vector mới có hiệp phương sai là ma trận đơn vị. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening\_transformation}

And this is what it looks like:

It's quite sparse. Do we have anyway to make it look normal?
Thank you

You could use the https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl package for the url, which would allow line breaks.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

use url package and \url{http......} then you will allow line breaking in the url and get better paragraph justification

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz omgg sorryy. :( I love your point

Oh i add the line \usepackage{xurl} and it works. Thank youuuuuuu

I’m voting to close this question because it's solved in comments with 99% probability it's a duplicate nobody's found.

@cfr because they're so niceee. Btw i'm figuring how to close the question..

Sorry? What are so nice? Or who? You can't close the question. It'll get closed when enough people vote to close it.

This question is similar to: How does one typeset a URL?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

In addition to the above suggested duplicate, could somebody with the necessary privileges, please add https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url as additional dupe target? Together these two dupe targets should cover both the missing \url{...} as well as adding more flexible line breaks.

Just add a package: \usepackage{xurl} then use \url{http..} in the footnote to break the line.
