# Remove URL in IEEEtran bibliography

Tags: bibtex, conditionals, urls, ieeetran

The question refers to the topic: [Disabling URLs in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26318/disabling-urls-in-bibliography)

Could you think of a solution, which allows to have the URL in bibliography entry or not depending on the entry type. I. e. remove the URL from the bibliography for `article`-type entries, but keep it for `manual`- or `techreport`-type entries?

Comment: Just for the practical side, I found it useful to not to keep URL address in the `.bib` file since `DOI` is exactly for that and technical reports etc. don't have one.

Answer (score 9):

To disable the printing of URLs for certain entry types -- say, `article` and `book` -- while using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, just do the following:

- Locate the file `IEEEtran.bst` in your TeX distribution. On mine,
  the file is at `TEXMFDIST\bibtex\bst\IEEEtran\IEEEtran.bst`. Copy
  this file to, say, `myIEEEtran.bst`. Open the file `myIEEEtran.bst` in an ASCII editor.
- Search for the line that contains `FUNCTION
  {article}`. (In my version of the file, it's at line 1964.) About a
  dozen lines further down from that line, there should be a line that contains

  ```
  format.url output
  ```

  Delete this line.
- Repeat the preceding step for all other entry types, e.g., for the entry type `book` (which follows directly after `article` in this .bst file) for which you also want BibTeX to ignore any URL-related information.
- Save the `.bst` file, run `texhash` (or the equivalent command for your TeX distribution), if necessary, to update the filename database, and specify `\bibliographystyle{myIEEEtran}` from now on.

Note that this approach does *not* require you to mess with the contents of your `.bib` file(s). All it does is to instruct BibTeX to ignore the `url` field, if available, for entries of type `article` and `book`. If, in the future, you need to use a different bibliography style -- say, the original `IEEEtran` bibliography style! -- just change the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` command.

**Addendum: apacite:**

If you want to remove URLs from bibliographies processed with the `apacite` bibliography style, comment out or remove the following directive from `apacite.sty` (and rename the file suitably):

```
  % url empty$
  %   'skip$
  %   { % Clear the stack
  %     duplicate$ empty$
  %       'skip$
  %       { output.new.block }
  %     if$
  %     format.url
  %   }
  % if$
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer - works perfectly! (I just copied the IEEEtran.bst file to the directory of the TeX-Source-Code, so that I am able to compile the TeX-code on any other system without having to write in the program-files-section of the respective machine. This also makes running texhash unnecessary.)

Comment: Nice answer. Here is a bash command which just removes all the URL entries and creates a new `IEEEtranWoUrl.bst`: `cat IEEEtran.bs | grep -ve '^\ *format\.url\ output$' > IEEEtranWoUrl.bst`