# Remove abstracts from .bib?

Tags: bibtex

I want to remove all abstracts from a .bib (bibtex) file. I am constantly sending this file back and forth by email and currently the size is too large.

Note that the abstract field has multiple lines, so the `grep` approach [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26318/disabling-urls-in-bibliography) does not work.

Comment: Have you looked at `bibtool`?

Comment: gzipping it is likely to be easier, and make it smaller

Comment: oh, I found it. `bibtool -r bibtool.res ref.bib -o ref-fix.bib`, where `bibtool.rex` is a file containing the line `delete.field = { abstract }`. Thanks! If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: no I meant just use gzip to make your file smaller and don't worry about the abstracts a typical bib file will compress a lot

Comment: @AndrewSwann answer requested ^^ :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good tool for this sort of operation is the program [`bibtool`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibtool?lang=en).  To use it for removing particular field you need to create an resource file e.g. `remove-abs.rsc` containing the line

```
delete.field = { abstract }
```

Then invoke this on your original bib file `orig.bib` as

```
bibtool -r remove-abs.rsc orig.bib -o new.bib

@Article{test,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {A title},
  journal =  {J. Jour.},
  year =     2000,
  volume =   3,
  pages =    {6--23},
  abstract =     {Abstract text to be removed}
}
```

this produces

```
@Article{     test,
  author    = {Author, A.},
  title     = {A title},
  journal   = {J. Jour.},
  year      = 2000,
  volume    = 3,
  pages     = {6--23}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a text editor, like Sublime. 
Activate the Regex function (option+command+R on Mac) and look for:

```
abstract = {.*},
```

and substitute it with nothing.

This removes anything between `abstract = {` and `},`

You can apply this to other fields.

Comment: In Overleaf one has to escape the curly brackets (regexp mode on): abstract = \{.*\}
Also, the empty lines can be removed by replacing the following with nothing: ^$\n

Answer (score 0):

Outstanding recommendation from [Carlo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/161576/carlo-bianchi)!

If you are using Linux xed, you can use the following:

**abstract={[^}]*}**

Nowadays, you can also use an online AI service to help you with regular expressions with varied content.

(I can't comment because I don't have the requisite credits)