# Mendeley Export Citation Without Abstract

Tags: bibtex

I have searched on an answer to this question and have not yet found an answer.

Is there a way to export a .bib file from Mendeley which does not include the abstracts.

Manually removing abstracts from a bibtex file which have over 150 citations seems like a bad way to spend an evening!

Comment: Is the `abstract` field appearing in your bibliography? You can remove it automatically at compile time with `biblatex`. Please edit your question and add a full [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/87678)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This is *not* a good idea. What if you have the word 'abstract' anywhere in a title?

Comment: @AlanMunn Whoops. Wrong substitution indeed... It should be `sed -i '/^\s*abstract/ d file.bib` to remove only lines that start with `abstract`, ignoring leading spaces. I have never seen a bibliography style that prints the abstract, so the OP may wish to simply delete the abstract entries from the file. I under the need, some editors misbehave with very long lines. And I don't know of a Mendeley feature that allows to do what he wants...

Comment: This is question is not about `biblatex` in particular, so I have removed the tag. It would be possible to process an exported file with `abstract` fields with Biber to remove those fields. Would that be OK?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove abstracts from .bib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371401/35864) You could also use Biber's tool mode to do something similar.

Comment: I use a similar approach to @PhelypeOleinik (but in my editor).  I find that having the abstracts in there makes searching for entries harder.

Comment: For bibtex you can use bibtool to remove certain fields from entries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Biber's tool mode to remove the `abstract` field from a `.bib` file.

Place

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_align>true</output_align>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" level="user">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_set="abstract" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

in a file called `remabs.conf` into the same directory as your `.bib` file.

Then call Biber with

```
biber --tool --configfile=remabs.conf <yourbibfile.bib>
```

If

```
@book{elk,
  author = {Anne Elk},
  title = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses},
  subtitle = {Really Interesting Dinosaurs},
  date = {1970},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  location = {London},
  abstract = {Brontosauruses were huge beasts.},
}
```

is saved as `elk.bib`, the call `biber --tool --configfile=remabs.conf elk.bib` will result in a file called `elk_bibertool.bib` with the contents

```
@book{elk,
  author    = {Elk, Anne},
  location  = {London},
  publisher = {Monthy Press},
  date      = {1970},
  subtitle  = {Really Interesting Dinosaurs},
  title     = {On the Theory of Brontosauruses},
}
```

being placed in the same directory.