# Preserve @comment line with bibtool

Tags: bibdesk, bibtool

I just ran `bibtool` on my bib file (managed with BibDesk) to remove the abstract fields (with thanks to ananswer to [Remove abstracts from .bib?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371429/56834)). However, doing so removed the `@comment` line added by BibDesk.

Is there a way to preserve the `@comment` line (and my static groups!) when running `bibtool`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `pass.comments=on` preserves comments by "attach[ing] them to the entry following them" [1]

Hence, the following one-liner solves your question:

```
bibtool -- pass.comments=on -- delete.field={abstract} bibdesk.bib -o bibdesk_cleaned.bib
```

You might want to specify these options in a bibtool *.rsc file and load it using `-r preserve_bibdesk.rsc`. I tried to mimic the output format of BibDesk with such a bibtool resource file as closely as possible here: https://github.com/ge-ne/bibtool/files/4906579/preserve_bibdesk.zip

Notice that bibtool might affect fields with newlines (e.g., if you 'misuse' the *Annote* for comments) because "BibTool assumes that the text is typeset with (La)TeX at the end. Thus the rules for this target are taken into account." [3] Hence bibtool eliminates single line breaks and collapses multiple line breaks accordingly.

---

[1] BibTool Manual, p29: https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/bibtool.pdf

[2] BibTool Quick Reference: https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/biblio/bibtex/utils/bibtool/ref_card.pdf

[3] BibTool author clarifying newline behavior: https://github.com/ge-ne/bibtool/issues/77#issuecomment-657127528