# Disabling "[Online]. Available:" from References in IEEETran.cls in Overleaf

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

How do I remove "[Online]. Available:" from References in `IEEETran.cls` in Overleaf? I am currently using 
`\def\url#1{}` to disable the URL. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: Did you mean `IEEEtran.bst` (the bibliography style file) or `IEEEtran.cls` (the LaTeX document class file)? I would be very surprised if it turns out that the document class governs the insertion of strings such as `[Online]. Available:` in the formatted bibliographic entries. That's usually the job of the bibliography style file. Please advise.

Comment: Please also clarify your actual typesetting objective? Is it to suppress the typesetting of URL strings in the bibliography? If that's not the case, what else are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was wrong to assume that it was IEEEtran.cls. It should be IEEEtran.bst. Here is an example.       https://www.overleaf.com/6133299219cjwsjhyzpbnb.  Only the third reference shows the issue.

Comment: The code is unavailable without an account ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found a way around the issue: remove URL in Zotero (one-by-one, tedious) then export the bibLatex file. This may throw a couple of warnings in the overleaf which can be ignored.

Comment: With [Better BibTeX for Zotero](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/) it is (probably, I don't use it myself, so I can't be sure, but I would bet quite a lot on it) possible to remove URLs automatically.

Comment: This is indeed possible using BBT. You can just add the `url` field to `fields to omit` preference.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here worked:

[Disabling URLs in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26318/disabling-urls-in-bibliography)

The IEEEtran.bst v1.14 introduces a new option to disable URLs. Now you can create a bib file containing the following:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{MyBSTcontrol,
    CTLuse_url = "no",
}
```

Include this bib file along with other bib files, and invoke it via bstctlcite

```
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{MyBSTcontrol}
.
.
```

All URLs in the references will be gone.