# How to insert invisible linebreaks in urls?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, urls

I'm using biblatex and I'm quoting a commit on github that looks like this:

`http://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/693d92a1bbc9e42681c42ed190bd42b636ca876f`

The biblatex-entry looks like this,

```
@online{Torvalds11,
  author = {Linus Torvalds},
  title = {Linux Makefile: Commit 693d92a},
  url = {http://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/693d92a1bbc9e42681c42ed190bd42b636ca876f}
}
```

The result looks like this.

[image: Screenshot of bib entry]

UI tried to insert a space character but that didn't work. How to force latex to break that url at the end of the line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{biblatex}
  \bibliography{mwe}
 \usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
  \lipsum[100]\cite{Torvalds11}
  \printbibliography
 \end{document}
```

I found this: [How to deal with bibliography items containing long URLs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/how-to-deal-with-bibliography-items-containing-long-urls)
But the suggested answers are not compatible with my document as I'm using `hyperref` package already and it *should* automatically break urls at the end of the lines. I guess this url is a special problem.

Comment: Did you try discretionary hyphens (`\-`)in the URL? Does `\hyphenation` remove the error? Maybe try out `\hyp` from the `hyphenat` package. (cf. [Wikibooks article on Hyphenation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Text_Formatting#Hyphenation))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd resort to a work-around and use a URL shortener for this URL [1], since noone is going to type in this URL anyways...

[1] maybe even github's own: https://github.com/blog/985-git-io-github-url-shortener

Answer (score 7):

The `biblatex` package has a facility for this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{Torvalds11,
  author = {Linus Torvalds},
  title = {Linux Makefile: Commit 693d92a},
  url = {http://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/693d92a1bbc9e42681c42ed190bd42b636ca876f}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[100]\cite{Torvalds11}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

However, this affects *all* URLs.