# Spurious percent symbol in bibtex url

Tags: bibtex, urls

Using pdflatex and bibtex, this code gives me a spurious percent symbol.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
hello \cite{hello}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{android}
\end{document}
```

bib entry:

```
@misc{hello,
  author={{John Smith}},
  title={My Title},
  note={\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4213/how-to-deal-with-bibliography-items-containing-long-urls}},
}
```

Rendered doc:

[image]

Note the '%' at the end of third line. How to fix it?

Comment: this _1996_ comp.text.tex posting on the same issue has a promise that bibtex 1.0 will fix this, but unfortunately bibtex 1.0 still hasn't arrived... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.text.tex/a8LRzuN-JV4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bibtex` limits the line length and inserts line breaks with preceding percent
character. Usually the percent is the comment char, but this is not the case in `\url`, whose argument is read in verbatim manner.

This issue was fixed in:

> ```
> % ver 1.6 20-Jun-2002`
> % [...] ignore trailing %, [...]
> ```

Probably you are using a version of package `url` that is more than ten years old. The current version is `ver 3.3 12-Apr-2006`.

An update of package `url` should fix the problem. Also it might be possible that different versions are installed and the outdated version is found first.

Comment: thanks, I am using the default latex packages in Fedora 17. I seem to have quite a few url.sty files on the system but `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty` and
`/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty` seem to be the most likely ones to be used. One is version 1.4 (html/url.sty) and the other is version 3.2 (ltxmisc/url.sty). How to figure out which one is being used and change to the right one?

Comment: Ok, got it. just used `\usepackage{ltxmisc/url}`. All % problems fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: @r.v: This is a bug in your Fedora's TeX installation, because [TDS](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tds/tds.pdf) requires uniqueness for the files below `TDS:tex/latex/`.

Comment: @r.v: `\usepackage{ltxmisc/url}` does not solve all problems, because other packages (e.g. `hyperref`) might load package `url`. Also you get a `LaTeX Warning: You have requested package "url/url", but the package provides "url"` in the `.log` file. I would install the uptodate `url.sty` in `$TEXMFLOCAL/tex/latex/url/url.sty` or `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex/url/url.sty`.

Comment: I checked and found that the `html/url.sty` version was provided by the latex2html package while the other was provided by the standard texlive package. Perhaps the two should have been consistent. Thanks for showing how to override the system settings with the local ones.