# Word spacing in bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, urls

I am trying to eliminate these spacing. I've been looking and trying different things, but nothing seems to work properly. I am using `thebibliography` environment.

I am trying to evenly space it all. For ref 1, the website is spaced too far and for ref 2, I want it evenly spaced. Please help

[image]

And I deal with the same with plain text. I don't know if there is a general command for both biblo and plain text

[image]

Comment: You're obviously setting your bibliography manually (using a `thebibliography` environment), correct?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear, yes I am

Comment: \hbox{} is not an option bc I am writing an article that is supposed to have 2 col.

Comment: You have to allow more breakpoints in your URLs, and maybe consider raggedright alignment for a 2-col bibliography.

Comment: A MWE would help in seeing exactly what you are doing, but the `url` package gives good flexibility in creating breaks and allowing larger spaces around `/` characters if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[paper=a5paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

\begin{document}

Default bibliography:

\begin{thebibliography}{X}
  \bibitem{abc0}
  Adventech B+B SmartWorx. {\itshape Smart IoT Technologies for Adaptive
  Traffic Management Using a Wireless Mesh Sensor Network.} 19 November 2014.
  http://advantech-bb.com/smart-iot-technologies-for-adaptive-traffic-management-using-a-wireless-mesh-sensor-networks/.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.

  \bibitem{def0}
  Elsevier. {\itshape Data-driven smart-city-enabled traffic system modeling,
  analysis and optimization.}
  https://www.journals.elsevier.com/transportation-research-part-c-emerging-technologies/call-for-papers.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.
\end{thebibliography}

\newpage

First alternative:

\begin{thebibliography}{X}
  \raggedright
  \bibitem{abc1}
  Adventech B+B SmartWorx. {\itshape Smart IoT Technologies for Adaptive
  Traffic Management Using a Wireless Mesh Sensor Network.} 19 November 2014.
  http://advantech-bb.com/smart-iot-technologies-for-adaptive-traffic-management-using-a-wireless-mesh-sensor-networks/.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.

  \bibitem{def1}
  Elsevier. {\itshape Data-driven smart-city-enabled traffic system modeling,
  analysis and optimization.}
  https://www.journals.elsevier.com/transportation-research-part-c-emerging-technologies/call-for-papers.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.
\end{thebibliography}

\newpage

Second alternative:

\begin{thebibliography}{X}
  \bibitem{abc2}
  Adventech B+B SmartWorx. {\itshape Smart IoT Technologies for Adaptive
  Traffic Management Using a Wireless Mesh Sensor Network.} 19 November 2014.
  \url{http://advantech-bb.com/smart-iot-technologies-for-adaptive-traffic-management-using-a-wireless-mesh-sensor-networks/}.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.

  \bibitem{def2}
  Elsevier. {\itshape Data-driven smart-city-enabled traffic system modeling,
  analysis and optimization.}
  \url{https://www.journals.elsevier.com/transportation-research-part-c-emerging-technologies/call-for-papers}.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.
\end{thebibliography}

\newpage

Third alternative:

\begin{thebibliography}{X}
  \bibitem{abc3}
  Adventech B+B SmartWorx. {\itshape Smart IoT Technologies for Adaptive
  Traffic Management Using a Wireless Mesh Sensor Network.} 19 November 2014.
  \href{http://advantech-bb.com/smart-iot-technologies-for-adaptive-traffic-management-using-a-wireless-mesh-sensor-networks/}{http://advantech-bb.com/}.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.

  \bibitem{def3}
  Elsevier. {\itshape Data-driven smart-city-enabled traffic system modeling,
  analysis and optimization.}
  \href{https://www.journals.elsevier.com/transportation-research-part-c-emerging-technologies/call-for-papers}{http://www.journals.elsevier.com/}.
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.
\end{thebibliography}

\newpage

Fourth alternative:

\begin{thebibliography}{X}
  \bibitem{abc4}
  Adventech B+B SmartWorx. {\itshape Smart IoT Technologies for Adaptive
  Traffic Management Using a Wireless Mesh Sensor Network.} 19 November 2014.

  \href{http://advantech-bb.com/smart-iot-technologies-for-adaptive-traffic-management-using-a-wireless-mesh-sensor-networks/}{http://advantech-bb.com/}

  Accessed: 15 October 2017.

  \bibitem{def4}
  Elsevier. {\itshape Data-driven smart-city-enabled traffic system modeling,
  analysis and optimization.}

  \href{https://www.journals.elsevier.com/transportation-research-part-c-emerging-technologies/call-for-papers}{https://www.journals.elsevier.com/}

  Accessed: 15 October 2017.
\end{thebibliography}

\newpage

Fifth alternative:

\begin{thebibliography}{X}
  \bibitem{abc5}
  Adventech B+B SmartWorx. {\itshape Smart IoT Technologies for Adaptive
  Traffic Management Using a Wireless Mesh Sensor Network.} 19 November 2014.
  \href{http://advantech-bb.com/smart-iot-technologies-for-adaptive-traffic-management-using-a-wireless-mesh-sensor-networks/}{\ttfamily advantech-bb.com}
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.

  \bibitem{def5}
  Elsevier. {\itshape Data-driven smart-city-enabled traffic system modeling,
  analysis and optimization.}
  \href{https://www.journals.elsevier.com/transportation-research-part-c-emerging-technologies/call-for-papers}{\ttfamily www.journals.elsevier.com}
  Accessed: 15 October 2017.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

In the above example,

1. The original input.
2. Using a `\raggedright` alignment within the `thebibliography` environment that helps with line-breaking. One could even consider using `\RaggedRight` from [`ragged2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e).
3. Using [`url`](//ctan.org/pkg/url) (also provided by [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)) with addition line-breaking rules (see [How to deal with bibliography items containing long URLs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4213/5764)).
4. Using abbreviated URLs with full-length embedded hyperlinks when viewing online.
5. Placing the URL on a line of its own, shortened if possible.
6. Mixing (3) and (4) above, together with a drop of the protocol and path in lieu of keeping only the domain.

   [image]

   Online viewers of the content can still click the URL to go to the intended target. Offline viewers should be able to find the content online by starting with the URL domain.

Another option to consider might be a URL shortner. While this may standardise your online references (lengths), there's not much to be gained by the casual paper reader from the online identify if a URL is not legible (that is, `my.fancy.long.url` provides more value than `f.akeurl/1h3ial`).

For additional information and a discussion on this topic (using similar techniques suggested above), see [URLs: Some Practical Advice](https://style.mla.org/2016/11/02/urls-some-practical-advice/).