# Breaking paragraph into lines with courier in cals table

Tags: line-breaking, cals

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=10mm, bottom=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cals}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\normalfont

\begin{calstable}

\colwidths{
{15pt}
{10pt}
{515.60239pt}
}
\cals@paddingL=1pt
\cals@paddingR=1pt
\def\cals@borderT{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderB{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderL{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderR{0.2pt}
\brow
\alignR \cell{\strut E}
\alignC \cell{\strut =}
\alignL \cell{\strut this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text}
\erow

\end{calstable}

Why doesn't the text break in the rigth place? In case of using sfdeault, it's good. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to [How to get long \texttt sections to break](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299/15925).  By default the `tt` font does not have stretachable interword spaces and so there is not much room for TeX to manoevre when choosing line breaks.   Adding some stretchability improves the line breaking:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=10mm, bottom=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cals}
\makeatletter

\newcommand*\flextt{%
  \ttfamily
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
}

\begin{document}
\flextt

\begin{calstable}

\colwidths{
{15pt}
{10pt}
{515.60239pt}
}
\cals@paddingL=1pt
\cals@paddingR=1pt
\def\cals@borderT{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderB{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderL{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderR{0.2pt}
\brow
\alignR \cell{\strut E}
\alignC \cell{\strut =}
\alignL \cell{\strut this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text}
\erow

\end{calstable}

Why doesn't the text break in the rigth place? In case of using sfdeault, it's good. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's always a big deal trying to break words in `tt` fonts.

You can try using a `sloppypar` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{top=10mm, bottom=10mm, left=10mm, right=10mm}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cals}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\normalfont

\begin{calstable}

\colwidths{
{15pt}
{10pt}
{515.50239pt}
}
\cals@paddingL=1pt
\cals@paddingR=1pt
\def\cals@borderT{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderB{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderL{0.2pt}
\def\cals@borderR{0.2pt}
\brow
\alignR \cell{\strut E}
\alignC \cell{\strut =}
\alignL \cell{\begin{sloppypar}\strut this is the english text, this is the english text, 
this is the english text, this is the english text, this is the english text, 
this is the english text, this is the english text\end{sloppypar}}
\erow

\end{calstable}

Why doesn't the text break in the rigth place? In case of using sfdeault, it's good.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]