# How to replace text

Tags: macros

I'd like to write something like this:

```
\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and here}{here}{Latex}
```

It should output

> Text should be replaced Latex, Latex and Latex

How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What about `there`? Should `here` be replaced too, to give `tLatex`?

Comment: There are probably more than one approach for this.

Comment: @egreg In my case I will be replacing a keyword that doesn't occur in arbitrary text, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @egreg Updated the question. I'm looking for a way to replace 'eqn' and 'eqn.' (and 'eqn,')

Comment: I can't understand why you'd want to replace the “keyword”: why not simply type the equation where it belongs?

Comment: I'd like to use my \theorem command multiple times and define how it will look at one place, for all equations at once.

Comment: I found a soultion using regular expressions (like you did in your answer). I also deleted all unnececary edits from my question again to make it more helpful for other peole.

Comment: @Marian You may ask a new question about your real problem; I believe there are better ways to deal with it.

Comment: I have a solution now so anything I'd post here wouldn't be a question and probably considered spam. I can post my solution to pastebin if you want.

Comment: Too literal? \newcommand*{\replace}[3]{Text should be replaced \LaTeX{}, \LaTeX{} and \LaTeX{}}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A complex solution that only replaces complete words:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}% remove with recent LaTeX releases

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\replace}{mmm}
 {
  \marian_replace:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_marian_input_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l_marian_search_tl
\tl_new:N \l_marian_replace_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \marian_replace:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_marian_input_text_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_marian_search_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_marian_replace_tl { #3 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \b\u{l_marian_search_tl}\b } { \u{l_marian_replace_tl} } \l_marian_input_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_marian_input_text_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and here}{here}{\LaTeX{}}

\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and not there}{here}{\LaTeX{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler solution that replaces all occurrences:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\replace}{mmm}
 {
  \marian_replace:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_marian_input_text_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \marian_replace:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_marian_input_text_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_marian_input_text_tl { #2 } { #3 }
  \tl_use:N \l_marian_input_text_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and here}{here}{\LaTeX{}}

\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and not there}{here}{\LaTeX{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a way to replace this: `\replace{\replace{start}{start}{fail}}{fail}{success}\\
\replace{fail,}{fail,}{success}`

Comment: @Marian - I've provided an answer that sets up the macro `\replace` so that the result of `\replace{\replace{start}{start}{fail}}{fail}{success}` is correct, *viz.*, "success".

Comment: Got `LaTeX Error: File `l3regex.sty' not found.`.  Proposed walkaround: `\usepackage{xparse,expl3}` (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491456/123888)

Comment: @abukaj Since 2014 things have changed and loading `xparse` or `l3regex` is no longer necessary.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. :)
How can I make your (former) code `\replace{Mar.~19 -- Mar. 23}{--}{TO}` result in `Mar.~19 TO Mar. 23`?

Answer (score 29):

[image]

```
\def\replace#1#2#3{%
 \def\tmp##1#2{##1#3\tmp}%
   \tmp#1\stopreplace#2\stopreplace}
\def\stopreplace#1\stopreplace{}

\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and here}{here}{Latex}

\bye
```

written as plain tex but would work in latex too.

Comment: This is very elegant and the best answer here, congratulations. Unfortunately it is impossible to use such replacing on the token strings when we needn't to expand the tokens.

Comment: Is there any way to make the code replace `--` (works great) but not `---`?

Comment: @abukaj only by hiding `---` as `{---}` or similar

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to replace `---` without removing the braces, am I right?

Comment: @abukaj right. but this site doesn't really support discussion threads on years old answers, if you have a question, better to post a question

Comment: I have already posted: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680303/how-to-convert-a-dash-to-a-minus-for-ats-only

Answer (score 21):

This uses the higher-level macro `StrSubstitute` from `xstring` package. Use `[0]` as first optional parameter to replace **all** occurences of `here`, but as egreg stated in a comment, it will also replace in words like `where` or `there`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}




\begin{document}

\StrSubstitute[0]{Text should be replaced here, here and here}{here}{Latex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It uses Lua's powerful `string.gsub` function in the definition of the `\replace` macro. The macro `\replace` can be used recursively.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for luacode environment and \luastring macro

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function myreplace(s,a,b)
  x = string.gsub(s,a,b)
  tex.sprint ( x )
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code
\newcommand\replace[3]{\directlua{%
  myreplace( \luastring{#1}, \luastring{#2}, \luastring{#3} ) }}

\begin{document}
\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and here.}{here}{Latex}

\replace{\replace{start}{start}{fail}}{fail}{success}

\replace{fail,}{fail,}{success}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the follow-up query by @user61681: If you must replace every single instance of "here" with "LaTeX" in the entire document, and if you can't do so by performing a global search-and-replace operation in your text editor, the following approach may be of interest. It "works" by (a) setting up a Lua function that employs the `string.gsub` function to replace all instances of "here" with "LaTeX" and (b) assigning this Lua function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, in effect making it act like a preprocessor on the input stream *before* TeX starts doing any of its usual work.

Note that this approach will fail is your document contains macros or labels that contain the string `here`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} 
\begin{luacode}
function myreplace ( s )
   s = s:gsub ( "here" , "LaTeX" ) 
   return s 
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", myreplace , "myreplace" )}}

\begin{document}
Text should be replaced here, here and here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to edit this if I want it for whole tex document. The problem is to replace here by LaTeX everywhere. Of course I can include whole text in curly braces after \replace but something simple may be possible. The question is how to extend this to whole tex document.

Comment: @user61681 - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 4):

OpTeX provides the macro `\replstring\macro{from}{to}`. For example:

```
\def\replace#1#2#3{\def\tmp{#1}\replstring\tmp{#2}{#3}\tmp}

\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and here}{here}{\OpTeX}

\replace{Text should be replaced here, here and not there}{here}{\OpTeX}

\bye
```

prints:

> Text should be replaced OpTEX, OpTEX and OpTEX
>
> Text should be replaced OpTEX, OpTEX and not tOpTEX