# Emphasizing all occurrences of given word in document

Tags: listings, highlighting

Please forgive my naivety, but I have a fairly large TeX document and I was hoping that there was an easy way to do the following. I can create code blocks in the text using the following:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
TEST
\end{lstlisting}
```

This will give all words within the `lstlisting` a different font to distinguish it as code from normal text.

I was hoping that there was a way in which I can search the whole document and add these tags to a word. For example every time the word "TEST" appears, it is encased in:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
TEST
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! For me that seems like a job for your favourite editor's search and replace function (often, but no always, triggered by Ctrl+H). A TeX solution might be possible (there are some crazy things possible in TeX), but not really desirable, I would have thought. It might just be your example, but I think it can't hurt to note that there is also `\lstinline{TEST}` for single words in text flow.

Comment: Yeah thought that was an option its just I have used the word over multiple tex documents and included the documents as chapters in my m=ain tex file, so it would be tedious opening up every document and using find and replace

Comment: But it is much safer than making "TEST" active (not sure if that is possible) and let TeX do that itself. Notepad++ lets you do search-and-replace in entire directories of files, so that should not be the excuse.

Comment: Have a look at the related [Macro: Replace all occurrences of a word](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165218/35864) and to a lesser extent [How to replace text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213947/35864). So it is not entirely impossible...

Comment: I wouldn't use `lstlisting` for this, though. `lstinline` makes more sense, but beware! You may not like an automatic solution for stuff like this. It would be better and more maintainable to do a search/replace (perhaps with sed or the windows equivalent).

Comment: @moewe It's possible, just a *really bad idea*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Must be compiled with XeTeX.

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\SearchList{make-blue}{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}{test}
\SearchList{make-red}{\textcolor{red}{#1}}{maybe,different}
\SearchList{code}{\lstinline{#1}}{code}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
Hello, this is a test, Test, TEST.

But maybe you want a different test.

Some code.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that you can make an entire list case-sensitive with `\SearchList*` or a particular word case-sensitive with `\SearchList{...}{...}{...,*Word,...}`.

Comment: I've also managed to compile it with XeLaTex. I just would like to let others know about it.

Comment: @Rubens yes, and the XeLaTeX format uses the XeTeX engine :) You may be interested in [this jargonfile](http://seanallred.com/tex/2015/05/25/tex-terminology.html#engines).

Comment: I know you merely used the package and probably didn't write it, but what the hell is in the manual? I just opened it with `texdoc xesearch` and my computer went nuts. Eventually, the kernel killed Okular, freeing half of my 8G of RAM. I hate to think what using the package does, if merely opening the manual requires these kinds of resources! I only saw page 1 and it took most of 4G?! I was trying to figure out why this answer now gives an error, but I now have other problems.

Comment: @cfr It's uh–[definitely a little busy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3GLf.jpg) :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred Certainly my computer was busy! Usually, it kills Firefox when it runs out of memory, because Firefox is always the worst offender. I've never had Okular be before. (And I routinely have multiple instances of Okular, each with multiple tabs.)

Comment: In case you're interested, the follow-up is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415559/bold-all-occurrences-of-glossary-entries-in-sharelatex-with-xelatex?noredirect=1&lq=1. I'm not risking trying to read the documentation again.

Comment: @cfr If you'd like, you can probably use pdftk to remove the first page – the rest of the doc is reasonable :-) (and thanks for the link!)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Note that the search is case-sensitive:  while "TEST" is highlighted, "test", "Test", and "TeSt" are not.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacode,luatexbase}

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
function highlight_TEST ( line )
    return string.gsub ( line, "TEST", 
                         "\\textcolor{red}{\\texttt{TEST}}" )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer",
          highlight_TEST, "highlight_TEST" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

A test, Test, TEST, TeSt, tESt.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you could get case insensitivity by doing a regex replace instead.

Comment: @SeanAllred - Lua doesn't do regex (unless some custom module is loaded). Out of the box, it does pattern matching, which isn't quite as powerful as regex.

Comment: That's so sad :( Still, nice to see a LuaTeX solution :)