# How to ensure that all pages corresponding to the entries appear in the index are shown?

Tags: indexing

I have created an index list and want to ensure that all pages corresponding to the entries appear in the index are shown (i.e., if the term "urbanization" appears on p.34, 120, 150, then these three pages are shown in the index.)
Instead of doing it manually (searching the urbanization for the whole text and add the command \index every time it appears), is there a faster way of doing it? Thank you.

Comment: How did you create your index? Please include a small example in how you created the index in your document. If you used the `makeidx` package including page numbers in the index yould be the default behaviour: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
This is an example\index{example}.

\newpage

Example\index{example} is used on page 1 and 2.

\printindex

\end{document}`

Comment: @leandriis I think the OP perhaps has a list of words which they want in the index, and then wants their locations to be automatically found.

Comment: [This has been discussed before at latex.org](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30716), and I think it's a no go. One solution could be a global find and replace, or create a small script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recurrent topic. It has been commented several times that a good index need many  human decisions to include/exclude/modify/link terms, so an automatic index generally ist not regarded as a good idea.

Said that, with `xelatex` and `xesearch`, changing a bit [this answer to format acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549929/11604), seems to work at some extent:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=3mm,bmargin=5mm,footskip=1mm,paperheight=8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}  \makeindex 
\usepackage{xesearch}
\UndoBoundary{-} % allow hyphens!!
\SearchList{index}{#1\index{{#1}}}{antibod?,covid?,infection,rna,DNA,*ELISA,*WHO,?pcr,%
RT-pcr,Multiplex-PCR,usa,UK,SARS?,virus,sensit?,test?}

\begin{document}
Mr. So and So, from the 
WHO, % organization, must be indexed  
\newpage
who % common word, must be not indexed
has announced yesterday in the UK and the USA that the 
ELISA % method acronym, must be indexed  
\newpage
test to detect antibodies against SARS-CoV-2 \newpage\newpage\newpage    
in COVID-19 patients with  with first signs of the disease is useless,  
said now that even PCR methods, \newpage\newpage   
like RT-PCR \newpage 
nested PCR,\newpage 
quantitative PCR,\newpage\newpage\newpage\newpage       
and Multiplex-PCR test, \newpage\newpage\newpage               
used too early in the course of infection 
are not enough sensitives.\newpage
On the other hand, the researcher  
Elisa % Woman name, must be not indexed
 Whoknow proposed a WHO meetings to discuss the 
disgnostic protocols of SARS and RNA virus and  the sensitivity of a new indirect antibody test.  
 
\StopList {index}
\newpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```