# How to get the headers to display the chapters name?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I have the following WME:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}


\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[OC]{\thechapter.\quad\chaptertitle}% Author on Odd page, Centred
  \fancyhead[EC]{\thechapter.\quad\chaptertitle}% Title on Even page, Centred
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule of .4pt
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Using this WME, the headers only display the chapter number. How can I get the headers to display the chapters name?

Comment: `\chaptertitle` is a  `titlesec` command, not `fancyhdr`. I don't think both packages cooperate.

Comment: How would you do it using fancyhdr?

Comment: A priori, I don't know. I'll try to find a way, but it's much easier with `titleps`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `\leftmark`.

[image: leftmark]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}


\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[OC]{\leftmark}% Author on Odd page, Centred
  \fancyhead[EC]{\leftmark}% Title on Even page, Centred
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule of .4pt
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

---

Here's a version without "CHAPTER":

[image: without]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn {Nx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\replace}{mmm}
 {
  \pintodoido_replace:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\tl_new:N \l_pintodoido_input_text_tl
\tl_new:N \l_pintodoido_search_tl
\tl_new:N \l_pintodoido_replace_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pintodoido_replace:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_set:Nf \l_pintodoido_input_text_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_pintodoido_search_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_pintodoido_replace_tl { #3 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \b\u{l_pintodoido_search_tl}\b } { \u{l_pintodoido_replace_tl} } \l_pintodoido_input_text_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_pintodoido_input_text_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[OC]{\replace{\leftmark}{Chapter}{}}% Author on Odd page, Centred
  \fancyhead[EC]{\replace{\leftmark}{Chapter}{}}% Title on Even page, Centred
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule of .4pt
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the /leftmark outputs the horrible 'Chapter 1. Introduction'. I want '1. Introduction'. How would you do this?

Comment: @PintoDoido See the edited post. Commands from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213952/124577).

Comment: Sorry you're code contains typos! Check out how many 'pintodoidos' you've got!

Comment: @PintoDoido Where's that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\quad#1}{}}%
}
```

to remove the chaptername from the header entry.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\quad#1}{}}%
}
\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}% Header rule of .4pt
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe there is no need for an additional page style and you can use the `fancy` style:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=28pt,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{10pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\quad#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}%
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-40]
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.