# ConTeXt: Replace matching substring with macro output

Tags: context, strings, text-manipulation, xml

## Background

Looking to replace a string within a document with an equivalent string created using a macro. For example, I'd like to replace "McAnulty" with "\Mac Anulty".

## Problem

When using an XML document as the input source, replacing the string means not being able to flush the inner XML elements. The result:

[image: flush output]

## Code

The following code creates an XHTML document, replaces "McAnulty" with "\Mac Anulty", but cannot flush the XML.

```
\startbuffer[main]
<html>
  <p>“Mr. McAnulty, I presume?”</p>
  <p>Regular text. <em>Irregular text.</em></p>
</html>
\stopbuffer

\startxmlsetups xml:xhtml
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{*}{-}
  \xmlsetsetup{\xmldocument}{html|p|em}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:html
  \startdocument
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopdocument
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:p
  \xmlfunction{#1}{p}
  \par
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:em
  \dontleavehmode{\em\xmlflush{#1}}
\stopxmlsetups

\startluacode
function xml.functions.p( t )
  rep = { [1] = { "McAnulty", "\\Mac Anulty" } }
  x = lpeg.replacer( rep ):match( tostring( xml.text( t ) ) )

  buffers.assign( "p", context( x ) )
  context.getbuffer{ "p" }
end
\stopluacode

\xmlregistersetup{xml:xhtml}

\def\Mac{%
  % Determine the sizes of 'M' and 'c'.
  \newbox\MacMBox%
  \setbox\MacMBox\hbox{M}%
  \newbox\MacCBox%
  \setbox\MacCBox\hbox{c}%
  %
  % Cheat to dynamically derive the kerning size by putting Mc in a box.
  %
  \newbox\MacKernBox%
  \setbox\MacKernBox\hbox{\inframed[offset=\zeropoint, width=fit]{Mc}}%
  \def\MacDelta{\dimexpr\wd\MacKernBox-\wd\MacMBox-\wd\MacCBox\relax}%
  \def\MacUWidth{\dimexpr\wd\MacCBox-.75\MacDelta\relax}%
  \def\MacRule{\vrule width \MacUWidth height .04em depth \zeropoint \relax}%
  \def\MacKern{\dimexpr\wd\MacKernBox-\wd\MacMBox-\wd\MacCBox\relax}%
  \def\MacHeight{\dimexpr\ht\MacMBox-\ht\MacCBox\relax}%
  %
  % Write Mc, where c has a macron, to the document.
  %
  M{%
    \dontleavehmode{\raisebox{\MacHeight}\hbox{c}}%
    \kern-1.04\MacUWidth
    \MacRule
    \kern.08\MacUWidth
  }%
}%

\xmlprocessbuffer{main}{main}{}
```

## Question

How can pre-processing occur (e.g., string replacement) while still being able to apply other XML setups to XHTML elements?

## Related

- [Replacing a substring from a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/384743/2148)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\cldcontext` allows malicious users to execute arbitrary commands by abusing string escaping. Instead of expanding a TeX parameter inside of a Lua string, define a new TeX command that takes the string as an argument, such as:

```tex
\startluacode
local function processmac( t )
  rep = { [1] = { "McAnulty", "\\Mac Anulty" } }
  context(lpeg.replacer( rep ):match( t ))
end

interfaces.implement {
  name      = "processmac",
  arguments = { "string" },
  public    = true,
  actions   = processmac,
}
\stopluacode

\startxmlsetups xml:p
  \expandafter\processmac{\xmlflush{#1}}
  \par
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:em
  \dontleavehmode{\em\xmlflush{#1}}
\stopxmlsetups
```

You can test with this HTML input:

```html
<html>
  <p>“Mr. McAnulty, I presume?”</p>
  <p>]] .. (os.execute("touch /tmp/filename.txt") and '') .. [[</p>
  <p>Regular text. <em>Irregular text.</em></p>
</html>
```

to see that the malicious content has not been executed.

---

A more general solution defines the replacement values inside `userdata`, which can then be overloaded for different documents. Here's the skeleton:

```
\startluacode
userdata = userdata or {}

userdata.TextReplacements = {}

local function TextReplacement( text )
  context( lpeg.replacer( userdata.TextReplacements ):match( text ) )
end

interfaces.implement {
  name      = "TextReplacement",
  arguments = { "string" },
  public    = true,
  actions   = TextReplacement,
}
\stopluacode
```

Then, elsewhere, flesh out the replacements, such as:

```
\startluacode
userdata = userdata or {}

userdata.TextReplacements = { 
  [1] = { "McGenius", "\\Mac Genius" },
  [2] = { "a.m.", "\\cap{am}" },
  [3] = { "p.m.", "\\cap{pm}" },
}
\stopluacode
```

Using this approach, the replacement texts can vary depending on the needs of a particular document.