# latex text manipulation of \ref ouput

Tags: text, text-manipulation

For some reason I need to manipulate the output of the `\ref` command to match the patter of four digits without dots.
For example:

```
\title{A Very Simple \LaTeXe{} Template}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:section1}
\subsection{Section 1.1}\label{sec:section11}

\ref{sec:section11}

\end{document}
```

The output of `\ref{sec:section11}` is "1.1" but I need it to "be 0011".

I get some code working using `xparse` and `l3regex` I found here: [How to replace text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213947/how-to-replace-text), but this only works with plain text.

```
 \replace{1.1}{.}{} results in 11
 \replace{\ref{sec:section11}}{.}{} results in 1.1
```

Comment: Hi, did you look at the `hyperref` package documentation ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What would be the general rule?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform string substitutions it is better to use `\getrefnumber` from the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package instead of `\ref`. It is an expandable version of `\ref` that can be used for things like string substitutions.
Some of the answers to the question you linked to still might not work out of the box with `\getrefnumber` though if they do not first expand their arguments (and thus perform substitutions on `\getrefnumber{sec:section11}` instead of the on `1.1`).

Here is a possible solution that uses the [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package.
I don't know precisely by what procedure 1.1 is supposed to be transformed into 0011, so this probably doesn't precisely do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
% \usepackage{hyperref} %% Optional
%% N.B. refcount is automatically loaded by hyperref, so you don't need both

\usepackage{xstring} %% Package for string manipulation

\DeclareRobustCommand*\myref[1]{\formatsectionnumber{\getrefnumber{#1}}}
\newcommand*\formatsectionnumber[1]{%
  \begingroup
  %% Prepend and append two 0's, perform the substitution and store the result in \temp:
  \StrSubstitute[0]{00#100}{.}{}[\temp]%
  %% Store the first four characters in \temp:
  \StrLeft{\temp}{4}[\temp]%
  %% Print the result
  \temp
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}\label{sec:section1}

\subsection{Section 1.1}\label{sec:section11}

Section~\myref{sec:section1} has a subsection which we will call \myref{sec:section11}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The output of `\ref` is a sequence of commands for *printing* the number. You want an expandable version, which is provided by `refcount`.

With the help of `expl3` it's not difficult to get what you want (but the precise rule is mysterious).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% define an expl3 version
\cs_new_eq:NN \christian_getrefnumber:n \getrefnumber
% allocate a tl variable
\tl_new:N \l__christian_bizarreref_tl
% the main command
\NewDocumentCommand{\bizarreref}{m}
 {
  % get the reference number and store it
  \tl_set:Nx \l__christian_bizarreref_tl { \christian_getrefnumber:n { #1 } }
  % remove all periods
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__christian_bizarreref_tl { . } { }
  % pad with zeros
  \prg_replicate:nn { 4 - \tl_count:N \l__christian_bizarreref_tl } { 0 }
  % the reference
  \tl_use:N \l__christian_bizarreref_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}\label{sec:section1}
\subsection{Section 1.1}\label{sec:section11}

\bizarreref{sec:section11}

\end{document}
```

[image]