# Replace _{\mu with ^{\mu

Tags: pdftex, substitution

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213950/35990), I wrote a command that allows me to write `\cont*{(D_\mu\phi)}` to get the effect of `(D_\mu\phi)^\dagger(D^\mu\phi)`.

```
\def\replace#1#2#3{%
  \def\tmp##1#2{##1#3\tmp}%
    \tmp#1\stopreplace#2\stopreplace}
\def\stopreplace#1\stopreplace{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cont}{\@ifstar\@@cont\@cont}
\newcommand{\contsubst}[1]{\replace{#1}{_\mu}{^\mu}}
\def\@cont#1{{#1}\contsubst{#1}}
\def\@@cont#1{{#1}^\dagger\contsubst{#1}}
\makeatother
```

The problem is that this obviously doesn't work if `\mu` is inside curly braces, for things like `F_{\mu\nu}`.

I tried defining `\contsubst` like this

```
\edef\LB{\string{}
\newcommand{\contsubst}[1]{\replace{\replace{#1}{_\mu}{^\mu}}{_\LB\mu}{^\LB\mu}}
```

but that doesn't work.

**Edit:**

Here are some more examples of what the command should do:

```
\cont{A_\mu}  ->  A_\mu A^\mu
\cont{F_{\mu\nu}}  ->  F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}
\cont*{\phi}  ->  \phi^\dagger \phi
\cont*{(D_\mu\phi_1)}  ->  (D_\mu\phi_1)^\dagger (D^\mu\phi_1)  % subscript 1 stays a subscript
\cont*{\Phi_{\mu\nu}}  ->  \Phi_{\mu\nu}^\dagger \Phi^{\mu\nu}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should put emphasis on `\mu`: the summation index can be anything.

Just typeset twice the argument, but changing the first `_` into `^`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cont}{sm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_suthree_cont_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \_ } { \cU\^ } \l_suthree_cont_tl
  #2 \IfBooleanT{#1}{\sp{\dagger}} \tl_use:N \l_suthree_cont_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_suthree_cont_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\cont{A_\mu}$  $A_\mu A^\mu$

$\cont{F_{\mu\nu}}$  $F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$

$\cont*{\phi}$  $\phi^\dagger \phi$

$\cont*{(D_\mu\phi_1)}$ $(D_\mu\phi_1)^\dagger (D^\mu\phi_1)$

$\cont*{\Phi_{\mu\nu}}$ $\Phi_{\mu\nu}^\dagger \Phi^{\mu\nu}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd not pursue this idea, though. Since the thing you are using is neither a subscript nor a superscript, but both, I'd use a different character to denote it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\cont}{sm}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_suthree_cont_sub_tl { #2 }
  \tl_set_eq:NN \l_suthree_cont_sup_tl \l_suthree_cont_sub_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \? } { \cD\_ } \l_suthree_cont_sub_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \? } { \cU\^ } \l_suthree_cont_sup_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_suthree_cont_sub_tl
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\sp{\dagger}}
  \tl_use:N \l_suthree_cont_sup_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \l_suthree_cont_sub_tl
\tl_new:N \l_suthree_cont_sup_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\cont{A?\mu}$  $A_\mu A^\mu$

$\cont{F?{\mu\nu}}$  $F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$

$\cont*{\phi}$  $\phi^\dagger \phi$

$\cont*{\phi_1}$  $\phi_1^\dagger \phi_1$

$\cont*{(D?\mu\phi_1)}$ $(D_\mu\phi_1)^\dagger (D^\mu\phi_1)$

$\cont*{\Phi?{\mu\nu}}$ $\Phi_{\mu\nu}^\dagger \Phi^{\mu\nu}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right that Lorentz indices can be indicated by letters other than μ or ν. But your approach is less general in a different way. It assumes that only and always the first subscript carries Lorentz indices. E.g. `\cont*{\phi_1}` will come out as `\phi_1^\dagger \phi^1`. And for numeric indices (actually anything other than greek) I'd want `\phi_1^\dagger \phi_1`.

Comment: I've upvoted both answers, because I learned something from both. Sorry if the question was not very straightforward. It can be hard to communicate implicit assumptions.

Comment: @SU3 In this case it would be much easier to denote the summation index or indices with a different character than `_`, say `?`.

Comment: I like this suggestion. It is more general and reflects the different nature of the index.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and patch the mandatory argument, replacing `_` with `^`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\cont}{s m}{%
  \def\mArg{#2}
  \patchcmd{\mArg}{_}{^}{}{}% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
  #2
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{^\dagger}
  \mArg
}

\begin{document}

$\cont{A_\mu}$ % A_\mu A^\mu

$\cont{F_{\mu\nu}}$ % F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}

$\cont*{\phi}$ % \phi^\dagger \phi

$\cont*{(D_\mu\phi_1)}$ % (D_\mu\phi_1)^\dagger (D^\mu\phi_1)  % subscript 1 stays a subscript

$\cont*{\Phi_{\mu\nu}}$ % \Phi_{\mu\nu}^\dagger \Phi^{\mu\nu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, that's not what I wanted. I've added more examples to make things clearer. Your version gives me what looks like `F_{\mu}\nu F^{\mu}\nu` for `\cont{F_{\mu\nu}}` and a bunch of NoValue for `\cont*{\phi}`.

Comment: @SU3: Yes. I'm *expecting* a `_` in the input, since you didn't provide anything else. You should be more clear in your question presentation and include all possibly inputs.

Comment: @SU3: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'll give your updated solution a try. But in the mean time I've figured out how to do this with xparse + l3regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `xparse` + `l3regex`.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn                                                      
\NewDocumentCommand{\cont}{sm}                                     
{                                                                  
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}                                       
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {\cD_(\cB.?\c{[mn]u})} {\cU^\1} \l_tmpa_tl
  {#2} \IfBooleanT{#1}{^\dagger} \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl              
}                                                                  
\ExplSyntaxOff
```