# Text is out of borders in the list of items

Tags: lists

Right now I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{itemize}
    \item Обьект класса \texttt{параметр}, репрезентирующий частоту тиков счётчика. Имя объекта -- \texttt{frequency}.
    \item Обьект класса \texttt{событие}, циклически создающий сигналы с частотой \texttt{1/frequency}. Имя объекта -- \texttt{event}.
    \item Обьект класса \texttt{порт}, используемый для передачи сгенерированного \texttt{event}'ом сигнала. Имя объекта -- \texttt{tick}.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

in my code. How can I separate the word `frequency` between the lines without `\\` and other crutches?

[image]

Comment: You're being unlucky; add a word to the paragraph.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299/120578

Comment: "`\texttt{Period}`" fits perfect (or `\texttt{Period\footnote{\texttt{1/frequency}}}` if you prefer)