# How can I justify text with line number in Verbatim environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verbatim, fancyvrb, linenumber

My minimal file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\bf,commandchars=\^\#\*,baselinestretch=1,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
    \begin{document}
    ^justifying^pbox#12cm*#The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red. Beneath the petals are five sepals (or in the case of some Rosa sericea, four). These may be long enough to be visible when viewed from above and appear as green points alternating with the rounded petals. There are multiple superior ovaries that develop into achenes.[4] Roses are insect-pollinated in nature.*
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

But the `right side` of my `text` is not `align` correctly. My `line number` is not correctly too. 
And also I have the below warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, do you have `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` twice on purpose?

Comment: Do you require use of `verbatim`, or do you just want it to look a certain way? You might be better off making it look like `verbatim` without actually using `verbatim`.

Comment: @AML No. I require using verbatim.

Comment: @AML Thanks a lot for your bounty for my question

Comment: @SH.Madadpour: Your example doesn't need the use of `verbatim` or `Verbatim`. Why do you need it?

Comment: @Werner. My dear Werner; all of my codes in my book have the same structure with Verbatim environment. they have the same number and other options. Do you have a new idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/799/36296

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pbox}

\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}


\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\bf,commandchars=\^\#\*,baselinestretch=1,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
\begin{document}
^justify^pbox#12cm*#The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red. Beneath the petals are five sepals (or in the case of some Rosa sericea, four). These may be long enough to be visible when viewed from above and appear as green points alternating with the rounded petals. There are multiple superior ovaries that develop into achenes.[4] Roses are insect-pollinated in nature.*
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Maybe a simple alternative to number every line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}
\ttfamily
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\justify

\verb|\begin{document}|

The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red. Beneath the petals are five sepals (or in the case of some Rosa sericea, four). These may be long enough to be visible when viewed from above and appear as green points alternating with the rounded petals. There are multiple superior ovaries that develop into achenes.[4] Roses are insect-pollinated in nature.

\verb|\end{document}|
\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot . The text was aligned successfully. But the line numbers is not correct.

Comment: @SH.Madadpour From the point of view of the verbatim environment it is only a single line because it only sees the pbox. If you want automatic line breaking I suggest to use the `Listings` package.

Comment: @samcarter Would you kindly add a `listings` version, and then I will award you the bounty?

Comment: @AML Thanks a lot for the bounty! Instead of the listings version I added one with linenumbers :)

Comment: @samcarter He accepted your answer, so I assumed that solved his issue  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 5):

There are three problems: the line number is in the middle of the paragraph, the paragraph is not justified and the line skip between the paragraph and the lines `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` is to small.

The first can be solved with the optional argument `[t]` to `\pbox`, which set the baseline of the `\pbox` to its first line.

The third problem can be solved by adding `\strut` to the beginning and end of the paragraph.

For the second problem, justifying the paragraph, a little bit of help from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/799/36296) (the same as in samcarters answer) is needed. But this sets the fontdimens globally, which may not be wanted. Therefore I wrote macros for storing, setting and restoring them. And to avoid having to type all of this every time, there is also a macro `\justifiedtt` with the same syntax as `\pbox` (which is uses internally).

Here are the results of the different parts of the solution (I just shortened the text a little):

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pbox}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@orig@fdiii
\newdimen\@orig@fdiv
\newcount\@orig@hych
\newcommand*\@set@interword{%
  \@orig@fdiii=\fontdimen3\font
  \@orig@fdiv=\fontdimen4\font
  \@orig@hych=\hyphenchar\font
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}
\newcommand*\@restore@interword{%
  \fontdimen3\font=\@orig@fdiii
  \fontdimen4\font=\@orig@fdiv
  \hyphenchar\font=\@orig@hych
}

\newcommand{\justifiedtt}[3][c]{\pbox[#1]{#2}{\ttfamily\@set@interword\strut#3\strut\@restore@interword}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
Original:
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\bf,commandchars=\^\#\*,baselinestretch=1,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
\begin{document}
^pbox#^textwidth*#The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red.*
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}

\noindent
With \verb|[t]|:
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\bf,commandchars=\^\#\*,baselinestretch=1,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
\begin{document}
^pbox[t]#^textwidth*#The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red.*
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}

\noindent
With \verb|\strut| at start and end:
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\bf,commandchars=\^\#\*,baselinestretch=1,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
\begin{document}
^pbox#^textwidth*#^strut#*The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red.^strut*
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}

\noindent
With \verb|\justifiedtt|:
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\bf,commandchars=\^\#\*,baselinestretch=1,firstnumber=1,stepnumber=1]
\begin{document}
^justifiedtt[t]#^textwidth*#The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red.*
\end{document}
\end{Verbatim}

\noindent
\verb|\justifiedtt| outside \verb|Verbatim| also works:

\noindent
\justifiedtt[t]{\textwidth}{The flowers of most species have five petals, with the exception of Rosa sericea, which usually has only four. Each petal is divided into two distinct lobes and is usually white or pink, though in a few species yellow or red.}

\end{document}
```